# Se puede conectarse a mi webmail cpanel usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, cpanel

Mi duda es si existe alguna fomar de conectarme a mi servidor de correos de cpanel, para manejar los correos, el que pueda crear algo tipo gmail por medio de SMTP, quiero hacer una app similar a la que seria Outlook, el que pueda manejar los correos de mi servidor, hay algun metodo de hacerlo?

Comment: Con solo Javascript en el navegador no es posible, necesitas una aplicación de servidor y puedes desarrollarla en el lenguaje de tu preferencia, como Javascript (NodeJS), PHP, Perl, Ruby, Python, etc.

Comment: Osea que si se puede desde NodeJS, crear un tipo banckend para eso?, pero como se hace?